# Too short loop and infinite loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to make a code that would represent the Law of Large numbers in mathematics. However, I've been having trouble trying to print 20 different numbers with one execution of a code. If I have the **for loop** limit to little (i.e. any number less than 12), it will only print out one number. If I have the limit too big (numbers bigger than 13), it will print out an infinite set of numbers.

```
var numPeople = [];
var coin = [0, 1];
var sameSide = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    numPeople.push(i);
}

function coinFlip() {
    for (var i = 0; i < numPeople.length; i++) {
        coinChance = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
        if (coinChance < 50) {
            coinSide = coin[1];
        } else {
            coinSide = coin[2];
        }
        numPeople[i] = coinSide;
    }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    coinFlip();
    for (var i = 0; i < numPeople.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i; j < numPeople.length - i; i++) {
            if (numPeople[i] === numPeople[j]) {
                sameSide.push(true);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(sameSide.length);
}
```

Comment: You have four for loops.  Which is causing the problem?  BTW, `coin[2]` doesn't exist, you mean `coin[0]`.

Comment: @AZNPNOY2000 What are you trying to model? How would you describe it from a mathematical standpoint (without writing code)?

Comment: For starters, I'm thinking that `coin[2]` does not exist.

Comment: You have two nested loops both using `var i` as their counter. These will both be the *same* `i`. Have one of them use another variable. Otherwise, when the inner `i` reaches `numPeople.length`, it will end the outer loop for small loop limits. For large loop limits, it will always reset `i` to be within the loop, so the loop never terminates.

Comment: @PaulRoub the inner one looks like it should be `++j`ing

Comment: You're using the `sameSide` array as a counter. It makes a lot more sense to set `sameSide = 0` up top and then do `sameSide++` in your loop rather than pushing `true` and counting them later.

Comment: @PaulS. Missed that problem. I was thinking of  the `i < 2` loop and the `i < numPeople.length` loop nested within each other.

Comment: The Law of Large Numbers problem I'm trying to create is if in a set of 10 people flip a coin, and x people will have the same side which is heads. The ratio of heads to coins will grow closer and closer as you increase the number of people flipping coins. So what I'm trying to do in the code is have the set of people flip the coin 20 times in order to compare the numbers. I will try to test the code by fixing the errors and improving my code with suggestions above when I have time